# how to check if a message has expired or not in activemq in the producer

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, jms-topic

Iam working on activeMQ where iam sending a message to the consumer from producer via the queue.Assume that my consumer has failed due to some reason.
I have set the expiry time to the message as 15 mins so the message from producer stays on the queue and expires after 15 minutes.
How do i check programatically & ultimately get notified if the activeMQ message has expired or not in queue **in producer only not in consumer**(This is due my design).

The code snippet is as below.

**Initialization code**

```
public void init() {
        try {
            final LocalProperties config = new LocalProperties();
            final ConnectionFactory factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(config.getActiveMqConnection());
            this.connection = factory.createConnection(config.getActiveMqUser(), config.getActiveMqPassword());
            this.connection.start();
            this.session = this.connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            final Destination destination = this.session.createQueue(QUEUE_NAME);
            this.producer = this.session.createProducer(destination);
            this.producer.setDeliveryMode(DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);
        } catch (final JMSException e) {
            _LOG.error("We could not open the active mq connection", e);
        }
    }
```

**Producer Code**

```
public Response PostMessages(
            final MessageDelivery body, final String messageId) {

        try {
            this.openConnection();
            // Create a messages
            final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE).create();
            final String json = gson.toJson(body);
            final TextMessage request = this.session.createTextMessage(json);
            request.setLongProperty(
                    "expiryTime",
                    900000
                    );
            request.setStringProperty("messageType", "com/messages/post");
            request.setBooleanProperty("deliveryNotification", false);
            request.setStringProperty("destination", "XXXX");
            request.setStringProperty("destinationType", "FILTER");
            _LOG.info(request.getText());
            // Tell the producer to send the message
            producer.send(request);

            //How to get the expired message after producer.send(request)

            return Response.status(Response.Status.ACCEPTED).build();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            _LOG.error("We could not send the message", e);
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }
    }*
```

Answer (score 1):

By default , if a message is expired and the message is not persistent it will be discarded and the application will not be able to get it. If it is a persistent setting you have in AMQ it will be moved to the DLQ

Details here : [Automatically Discard Expired Messages](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html)

Comment: Is there any possiblity using queue browser?as we get access to message.getJMSexpiration()

Comment: Chances are your application will not even get the message to access the properties (if the message already expired). You may want to re-process it from the DLQ if that is a possibilty

Comment: I read regarding **ActiveMQ.Advisory.Expired.Queue** but could not get any code example to implement.I want to monitor the producer queue to check the expired messages.If u can provide a code example for this it would be great

Comment: I just had a look at a good answer provided by Bruce here. I have not tried this myself , may be you want to create a JMS consumer that is watching this queue for any advisory message on expired messages. : http://activemq.2283324.n4.nabble.com/How-to-get-notified-on-expired-messages-td3453498.html